# How to fix a broken recovery partition (remove it) when repairing it is not possible?

Tags: macos, partition, recovery

My main system is bootable but disk utility says it needs to be repaired.

I can start **disk utility** from Live-USB which can verify my OS X partition but gives errors on checking the whole disk. The error is "unknown file system" - but it appears only after it found the main file system.

I guess my (hidden) recovery partition might be broken, since I cannot boot into it. Maybe this is the cause for disk utility to bring the error.

I would like to repair the recovery partition or at least delete it. I know there are tutorials of how to create a new one.

Comment: What is the model of mac being used?

Comment: iMac 2010 mid i7

Comment: For future reference, it is possible to use Internet Recovery by pressing Option-Command-R, giving the same result, but without having to create a live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my partition with

```
$ diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ Blank /dev/disk0s3
```

which created a blank space.

I then also had to **repair** the disk in disk utility. Since then everything works fine.